# How to keep the previous uploaded image (in db) after submitting a form without selecting a new image to be uploaded

Tags: php, image, forms, upload

I have a simple form for creating an article: *Title,image,category,body , etc..*
My problem is with the image input.

Selecting a new one and submitting everything works fine:

- the image is being uploaded to the server
- the title of the image is being saved to db
- and i can print it in the article.

By editing the whole form, filling all fields but leaving the image field as it is, and finally submitting, the image field value in db is changing to nothing.

*How can i configure the php file, so every time the user submits the
form without selecting an image (if there was an image pre uploaded in
 that article ) keep as submitted the previous image (from db) instead
of nothing.?*

---

If these informations can be of any help:

I can print the image like this : `<?php  echo '<img src="'.$results['article']->img.'" width="100px">'; ?>`

Simple input field for image:

```
<input type="file" name="fileToUpload" id="fileToUpload"  value="<?php echo $results['article']->img ?>" />
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What about something like this?

```
if(!empty($_FILES['fileToUpload']['name'])) //new image uploaded
{
   //process your image and data
   $sql = "UPDATE table SET name=?, image=?,... WHERE id = ?";//save to DB with new image name
}
else // no image uploaded
{
   // save data, but no change the image column in MYSQL, so it will stay the same value
   $sql = "UPDATE table SET name=?,... WHERE id = ?";//save to DB but no change image column
}
//process SQL query in $sql
```

Answer (score 2):

Make a if clause that checks if fileupload input is empty or not. If it is empty do not execute query.

Use input type="file" without attribute value.

```
<input type="file" name="fileToUpload" id="fileToUpload" />
```

Here is example for if clause

```
if(!empty($_FILES['fileToUpload']['name'])) {
        $origFile = $_FILES['fileToUpload']['name'];
        $tempFile = $_FILES['fileToUpload']['tmp_name'];
        $sizeFile = $_FILES['fileToUpload']['size'];

        /* UPLOAD CODE GOES HERE */
    }
```

Comment: Tnx Plamen. I did as you said but now after submitting (and a change in the title just for test and no image to select for second editing time ) no updates are being stored to db.

Comment: You must add field <input type="text" name="uploadedFileName" value="<?php echo $results['article']->img ?>" /> and $_POST['uploadedFileName'] give you the name for image in mysql. You can set custom value in this field and update the name.

Comment: fill previous value in the text field is wasteful, you will update image column with the same value! just add ELSE clause and save other values EXCEPT image...

Answer (score 0):

It worked , really thanks

short solution

1. check the file is not empty: `if(!empty($_FILES['fileToUpload']['name']))`
2. Take update query with mentioning image column in your table  in IF statement,
   **if images not uploaded, then it will upload**.
3. Take update query without mentioning image column in your table  in ELSE statement,if file is empty, it will upload

***CONCLUSION***

Next time when you update any other field the image won't get disappeared, meaning file path wont be empty in your database, and if already present it won't change unless you manually change it..